# remove search paths from arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ while cross compiling with sysroot

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I want to cross compile my c++ program for an arm beaglebone. Compilation and linking works, but the binary is linked to the wrong version of libstdc++ and execution fails with

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found
```

On my host I have:

```
strings /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/libstdc++.so | grep GLIBCXX_3
...
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
```

An image of the beaglebone is mounted on ~/bbsysroot:

```
strings ~/bbsysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3
...
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
```

So, clearly, there is a version mismatch. That version mismatch is hard to avoid, since the host system is a different distribution.

The compilation command starts with

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/home/user/bbsysroot
```

so I'm supplying the sysroot of the beaglebone to the compiler. I want that it looks for the libs in there and only in there. But

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --sysroot=/home/user/bbsysroot -print-search-dirs | grep libraries | sed 's/:/\n/g'
libraries
 =/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/
/home/user/bbsysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/
/home/user/bbsysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
/home/user/bbsysroot/lib/../lib/
/home/user/bbsysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/
/home/user/bbsysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
/home/user/bbsysroot/usr/lib/../lib/
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/
/home/user/bbsysroot/lib/
/home/user/bbsysroot/usr/lib/
```

shows, that it also looks on the host. I presume, that the host libraries have a higher priority and hence the wrong version is taken.

Is it possible to force the cross compiler to use the libraries from sysroot only? Or is that utterly wrong for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer, which might solve the problem, but i've moved on to another project since and can't test it. Though it might help others:

libstdc++ and also libgcc are actually part of the compiler and I think
that the best solution is:

- use compiler version used by the BBB system (or earlier version)
- upgrade those libraries on the BBB system
- use '-static-libstdc++' option

You can try to use never compiler with older libgcc and libstdc++,
but I think that gcc may reference some newer functions. g++
also links libgcc dynamically by default.